# Nginx rewrite with proxypass

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, node.js

I have an Nginx running in the front of a node js server (next.js). I'm trying to write my Nginx config in order to achieve this behavior,
I want to add the hostname as the first part in the path before proxy_pass to node js.

for example, the client will write `a.com/` or `a.com/product/...` or `a.com/**`.
my nextjs application except for something like [http://a.com/[:domainname]/...](http://a.com/%5B:domainname%5D/...). while the domain name is the same as the host.

so the goal is to change the URL from `a.com/**` to `a.com/a.com/**`, before passing that to nextjs server.

the nginx config i created  :

```
location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # if ($host = a.com) { proxy_pass http://site/a/; }
                # if ($host = b.com) { proxy_pass http://site/b/; }
                rewrite ^(/.*)$ /$host/$1 ;
                proxy_pass http://site;
        }
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks valid, you should check what's the upstream is getting in it's access log. Bet the answer is there. Though I suppose the main issue is that you forgot to pass the Host header:

`proxy_set_header Host <whatever the Host is expected on the upstream, definitely not $host though>`

But this would be the clue only if the upstream server isn't the default or only one.